# Is using == instead of === ok for null/undefined?

Tags: javascript

I currently have a variable that can be `null` as well as `undefined`. In both cases I want to leave the function:

```
if (myvar==null) return;
```

this works fine but I retrieve warnings from my IDE (VS) because `==` does not care about the type while `===` does. I am aware that `==` is generally be seen as bad style because of this.

Is this the exception from the rule? Should I simply ignore this warning and stick to the better readability or would the following be the recommend action?

```
if (myvar===null || myvar===undefined) return;
```

Comment: If you're just checking if some value is truthy or falsy, `==` is fine, but in some situations you need to check if a value is specifically equal to `null` or `undefined`, in which case you must use `===`. This happens most often when working with third party libraries. But don't stress about these little things; just make it work!

Comment: No. Ask your colleagues if they know the correct `==` semantics ...

Comment: "*Should I simply ignore this warning*" no - [**change it**](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq#allow-null)! All linting rules are configurable, so I'm not sure why people are so reluctant to configure them to suit their needs.

Comment: `if (!myvar) return;` for falsy

Comment: seems to me like you're just checking for "falsey" values. you can just use `if (!myvar) return;`

Comment: @Tunn `myvar = 0` or `""` will be caught in those situations while  `myvar == null` solves that potential bug. `myvar===null || myvar===undefined` is the same but it's honestly too long, especially if you've got multiple variables - `myvar1 == null || myvar2 == null || myvar3 == null` is much shorter.

Comment: @marvinIsSacul no, it's not falsy values -`myvar == null` is the same as `myvar===null || myvar===undefined` but not the same as `myvar===null || myvar===undefined || myvar===0 || myvar===""|| myvar===false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the lack of clarification.
If you're writing the code for yourself, it's fine as you know exactly what you're doing. But if a contributor find this code, they could either:

1. Not knowing how `==` works in case of `null` / `undefined`
2. Knowing how it works but not knowing if the use was intentional (if you *actually* want to check both `null` or `undefined`, or you wanted just check for `null` but used `==`)

The code should be clear, so often you find programmers adding comments before this check to specify that yes, they know what they're doing, and yes, it was intentional.

Eventually you get tired of that and start to use `myvar === null || myvar === undefined`.

It's more verbose, but it's clearer, and doesn't give room to misunderstanding.

Another thing I notice is creating custom fuction for such things, e.g. `isNil(myvar)` but despite the verbosity I prefer checking both values.

Answer (score 1):

`==` has very specific rules, and it normally recommended against because those rules are not intuitive. I would only condone using it if you have memorized the rules related to its behavior, as have all other devs who could possibly have to deal with your code (which most have not).

In this case, `a == null` returns `true` if `a` is one of `null`, `undefined`, or `document.all`, but not the other 4 falsely JS values ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), including why document.all is falsely). So unless you want it to match `document.all`, I would use `===`.

Additionally, using `===` in all places adds consistency to your code.